# How To Permit more than one developer to Edit the same code file in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm new in **TFS 2010** and config a source control. we want to work in a *single code file* in our solution (ReportViewer.aspx) but unfortunately when one of we check out the source code file other team member's can not be accessed to same source code and is locked.

in addition to that mentioned, All data binding of our reports distinguish in ReportViewer.aspx Handler.
this problem may be cause in other way, that any team member check out the **Solution File**
(e.g. adding a reference), other team member can't be accessed to locked File.

Comment: Turn on multiple check-out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242869.aspx

Comment: @EdwardThomson the setting of multiple check-out by default is selected in our client, but we can not have multiple check-out. do this setting must be done to the server of TFS?

Comment: Yes, the link I provided above is for configuring the server-side (it's a per-Team Project setting.)

Answer (score 1):

As Edward mentioned, you will need [multiple check-outs enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242869.aspx) so that multiple developers can work on a single file.  They will then need to merge their changes during the check-in process.

That should also resolve your issue with the Solution File getting checked out and preventing other users from making their own additions to the solution.

Comment: How the merging changes process? do TFS for us automatically or our team handle to merging of changes?

Comment: TFS will automatically determine if somebody else has checked in a change to the file since you checked out your version.  If there are conflicts, this will be reported to the user in their IDE.  They will then need to use their preferred merge tool to resolve the conflicts.